# Swing option other than JxTaskPane

Tags: java, swing, awt, swingx, jxtaskpane

I am using JxTaskPane to add menu items ..but i don't want to use it, as i don't want that expand and collapsed type of container .. i just want to arrange my menu items horizontally.

If i add it to panel than i am unable to add actions to it as JxTaskPane has a method ..

```
public Component add(Action action) {
}
```

so what can i use here ..or if there is no other choice, can i remove that expand and collapsed button. and also... how to arrange the items horizontally in JxTaskPane.

Currently I am having a JScrollpane inside that is a JXTaskPaneContainer then inside JXTaskPaneContainer there is JxTaskPane .

Please help me..

Thankx

Comment: Doesn't `JMenuBar` provide what you need?

Comment: that will not work. I have a scroll panel inside that i want the menu items.

Comment: You should be able to add the JMenuBar to  a JScrollPane. Or try adding a JToolBar to a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use `JMenuBar` subclass `JPanel` and add a method

```
public void addAction(Action a) {
  addComponent( new JButton(a) );
}
```

That panel could use any layout manager you want, e.g. `FlowLayout`.